# handlewatchkitextensionrequest not calling Async call in suspended state

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

From Apple watch extension, handlewatchkitextensionrequest is not calling async call and returns nill data to apple watch, below are code please help me out.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier watchKitHandler;
    watchKitHandler = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"backgroundTask"
                                                                   expirationHandler:^{
                                                                       watchKitHandler = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                                                                   }];


    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"request"] isEqualToString:@"NearestFacility"]) {

        [self NearestFacilityClicked];
        if (self.ary_WatchKitNearestFacility.count>0) {
        NSDictionary *response = @{@"response" : self.ary_WatchKitNearestFacility};
        reply(response);
        }
    }

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)NSEC_PER_SEC * 1),    dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:watchKitHandler];
    });
}


-(IBAction)NearestFacilityClicked
{

    // ASIFormdatarequest call
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In watch os 2 you need to use session for transferring the data between watch & iPhone.
First you need to initialise the WCSession in viewdidload()

```
if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
session.delegate = self
session.activateSession()
```

}

then to send the data you can use

```
 let transfer =  WCSession.defaultSession().transferUserInfo(applicationDict)
```

Then, on the receiving end, you'll need to implement session:didReceiveUserInfo: (Developer documentation). Note, according to Apple's "watchOS2 Transition Guide,"

> To begin communication, both your Watch app and your iOS app must have an active WCSession object. Typically, each app creates, configures, and activates a session object at launch time and stores a reference to it in a central location. When you want to send data, you retrieve the session object and call its methods.

Comment: Dear Fawaz , thank you very much for your reply , my watch os is 1.0.1 , still i am facing this issue :(

Comment: Dear Fawaz, i noticed that if i am passing nil reply or simple dictionary reply than its handled by extension method and when trying to pass numutablearray in reply than it gives me below error

Comment: Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=2 "The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply()  nsmutablearray , do you have idea about this ?